# C11/C++11 macro to associate a constant string to a literal integer

Tags: c++, string, c++11, enums

I already have a big set of C++ source code files containing calls to a logger function written in this way:

```
LogIx(_S("This is my msg"));
```

where:

```
#define _S(a)  (#a)
```

it works but my customer would like to put in production a logger not easily understandable (I don't agree so much, but anyway...). The source code base is very large so my idea is to modify as little as possible and associate a number (index) to each message and put all messages inside a table so that the number will be the index of the message in the table.

The first idea (that works) is find all the _S(...) messages, extract them from the source and populate an enum with their equivalent and then change the parameter inside each _S() with the enum tag. Of course it is not error prone and not very good thinking to add other messages in the future.

So I am thinking to a different solution using the preprocesor but seems it is not possible use a quoted string in a #define.

This piece of C++ source code doesn't work but show what I would like to do:

```
#define _V(a)  (#a)

const std::array<string, 3> s_logStrings = {
      _V("This is my msg"),
      _V("Param %s is: %d"),
      _V("Reset msg")
};

#define _S("This is my msg")   0
#define _S("Param %s is: %d")  1
#define _S("Reset msg")        2

int Log(size_t msgIndex)
{
   cout << s_logStrings.at(LogIx(msgIndex));
}

int main(void)
{
   std::cout << "Begin test" << std::endl;
   Log(_S("This is my msg"));
   std::cout << "End test" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}

#define _V(a)  (#a)

const std::array<string, 3> s_logStrings = {
      _V("This is my msg"),
      _V("Param %s is: %d"),
      _V("Reset msg")
};

#define _S(a) // ???? this is the problem... how define this macro?
// also a constexpr could be a good solution, the point is to don't
// add a function or a <map>

#define _S("This is my msg")   0
#define _S("Param %s is: %d")  1
#define _S("Reset msg")        2

int Log(size_t msgIndex)
{
   cout << s_logStrings.at(msgIndex);
}

int main(void)
{
   std::cout << "Begin test" << std::endl;
   Log(_S("This is my msg"));
   std::cout << "End test" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Any idea or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_S` and `_V`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

By turning your literal to type as `char_sequence`,
you may do something like:

```
template <char ... > struct char_sequence {};

// use gnu extension :/
template<class CharT, CharT... cs>
char_sequence<cs...> operator ""_seq(){
    return {};
}

template <class T, class Tuple>
struct index_in_tuple;

template <class T, class... Types>
struct index_in_tuple<T, std::tuple<T, Types...>> {
    static const std::size_t value = 0;
};

template <class T, class U, class... Types>
struct index_in_tuple<T, std::tuple<U, Types...>> {
    static const std::size_t value = 1 + index_in_tuple<T, std::tuple<Types...>>::value;
};

using MyMessagesTuple = decltype(std::make_tuple(
    "This is my msg"_seq,
    "Param %s is: %d"_seq,
    "Reset msg"_seq
));


#define _S(a)  (index_in_tuple<decltype(a##_seq), MyMessagesTuple>::value)

int main() {
    auto foo = _S("Reset msg");
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cb994634e74b761)